# Порядок переключения элементов Tab'ом в QWidgets

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Qt, C++. Набросал графический интерфейс через QtDesigner. На форме несколько полей ввода и кнопок. Столкнулся с тем, что кнопка Tab при использовании отрабатывает странно: элементы переключаются не последовательно, как ожидается, а хаотично. Судя по всему, в том порядке, в каком я размещал их в творческом порыве создания GUI.

Как можно отрегулировать поведение кнопки Tab, чтобы фокус между элементами окна переключался логично?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#setTabOrder, https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-tab-order.html

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @maestro:

В режиме QtDesigner верхнее меню "Правка" -> "Изменение порядка обхода". Затем просто кликаем по элементам в нужном порядке. Чтобы выйти из этого режима, переходим "Правка" -> "Изменение виджетов".